# Compare string character per character, split strings by length would work also

Tags: c

I have two strings and need to compare them AND state which characters are correct.

My code is:

```
char Palavra = "exemplo";
int Tamanho = strlen(Palavra),i;
printf("Which is your guess?\n");
char Palpite[Tamanho];
fgets(Palpite,Tamanho,stdin);
char Mensagem[50];
strcpy(Mensagem,"The following characters are correct: ");
    for(i=0;i<=Tamanho;i++){
        if(Palavra[i] == Palpite[i]) sprintf(Mensagem,"%s %i",Mensagem,i+1);
    }
    printf("%s",Mensagem);
```

I need to compare variables Palavra and Palpite, character per character and then say with one is correct.
Something like this:

Palavra = celular

Palpite = cilular

Answer should be: "The following characters are correct: 1 3 4 5 6 7"

But I am getting: "The following characters are correct: 1 3 4 5 6 8"

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain why you can't use `for(i=0;i<=Tamanho;i++){ if(Palavra[i] == Palpite[i]) ... do something }`?  It looks like `Palavra` and `Palpite` have the same scope.

Comment: `It would be pretty easy if I could access both variables as arrarys... But unfortunatelly this doesnt work` - but you absolutely can access both as arrays and it should work. What's not working?

Comment: Gee, sorry, just tested a bit deeper and found out my error isnt in for loop, its after that. Will update question, sorry for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably it does not work because you have assigned a pointer to an array to a char value.
Also it could be that you are stepping out of array bounds with for i<=Tamnho is causing some comparison problems/possibly crashes (if you are trying to change them).
But the logic behind the code is correct, so I don't see any other reason as to why it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is the issue:

```
int Tamanho = strlen(Palavra),i;
...
for(i=0;i<=Tamanho;i++){
   if(Palavra[i] == Palpite[i]) ... do something
}
```

`Palvara[Tamanho]` is going to be a null char.  Valid indices for `Palvara` with a non-null character are from `[0..Tamanho-1]`.   This corrects the bug:

```
for(i=0; i < Tamanho; i++){
   if(Palavra[i] == Palpite[i]) ... do something
}
```

Also, don't forget that Palpite's length might be less than Palvara's length.  Make sure you break out of your for-loop before dereferencing `Palpite[i]` if `i >= strlen(Palpite)`

Better:

```
int len = strlen(Palpite);
int count = (Tamanho <= len) ? Tamanho : len;
for(i=0; i < count; i++){
   if(Palavra[i] == Palpite[i]) ... do something
}
```

Comment: `int count = (Tamanho <= len) ? Tamanho : len;` : this is useless, because of `fgets(Palpite,Tamanho,stdin);` the length to consider is `strlen(Palpite)`, *Palpite* cannot be longer than *Tamanho*. Remark also even`fgets` can save the newline this is not a problem in that case

Comment: Palpite wont be greater than Tamanho as fgets considers only the same length as Palavra for Palpite

Comment: I tried 
```for(i=0; i < Tamanho; i++){
   if(Palavra[i] == Palpite[i]) ... do something
}
```
It didnt work either, same problem

Answer (score 0):

It worked as expected with this code, although that last if is a clear work around I am not really confortable using.

```
    int Tamanho = strlen(Palavra),i;
    printf("Which is your guess?\n");
    char Palavra = "exemplo";   
    char Palpite[Tamanho];
    fgets(Palpite,Tamanho,stdin);
    char Mensagem[50];
    strcpy(Mensagem,"The following characters are correct: ");
    for(i=0; i<=Tamanho; i++) {
        if(Palavra[i] == Palpite[i]) {
            if(i==Tamanho) {
                sprintf(Mensagem,"%s %i",Mensagem,i);
            } else {
                sprintf(Mensagem,"%s %i",Mensagem,i+1);
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%s",Mensagem);
```

Answer (score 0):

Code incurs *undefined behavior* (UB) due to attempting to access outside an array's range.

When `i==Tamanho`, `Palpite[i]` is bad.

```
char Palpite[Tamanho];
for(i=0;i<=Tamanho;i++){
  if(Palavra[i] == Palpite[i]) sprintf(Mensagem,"%s %i",Mensagem,i+1);
}
```

---

Code incurs *undefined behavior* (UB) due to attempting to access access and write to the same array with `int sprintf(char * restrict s, const char * restrict format, ...);`.  The `restrict` is a contract that the caller broke by using the destination as an later augment.

```
sprintf(Mensagem,"%s %i",Mensagem,i+1);
//      ^^^^^^^^         ^^^^^^^^  UB
```

Alternative code could have written to the end.

```
size_t len = strlen(Mensagem);
sprintf(Mensagem + len," %i",i+1);
```

Better code would use `snprintf()` to issue no buffer overrun.

---

A well warning enabled compiler would have warned about the type mismatch.  Save time, enable all warnings.

```
char Palavra = "exemplo";
```

---

UB for writing outside arrays bounds.  `char Mensagem[50];` is too small for  `"The following characters are correct:  1 3 4 5 6 8"` which needs 51.

Consider scaling `Mensagem[];` with a  more geneorus size and use `snprintf()` to avoid overflow.